# I have a ghost mouse pointer left over from login screen on my amd radeon r7 with 20.04.2

Tags: 20.04, mouse, radeon

Fresh install of 20.04.2 on Lenovo AMD Radeon R7 and integrated graphics. When I have logged in, there is an unresponsive ghost mouse pointer left in the middle of the screen where I used it to login. there is a new bigger pointer that works so I not disabled but the other smaller mouse is very distracting and weird!

Comment: Does the ghost mouse pointer appear after every reboot?

Comment: I re-installed as that got rid of the ghost - but yes, every time I booted :-)

Comment: Now - it's back! I used the screen scaling feature and now when I log in, I need to swap between scales before the ghost mouse disappears.